# express & angular directory structure and routing

Tags: angularjs, express

I'm new to express & angular, and after looking at some of the answers here at the forum I came across the express angular seed.

My question is regarding the dir struct & the routing.
The angular seed dir structure has a public directory which holds "all of the files to be used in on the client side" however, it also have a view directory which holds the views. 
What is the benefit from having it seperated? 
Why not having the views under the public directory, and let angular take care of templating & views and the client routes and in the server I will only need to add routes for for actual serving client requests.

Comment: "it also have a view directory which holds the views", which directory are you talking about?

Comment: The advantage of separating them is so that `node` can use them for rendering in the event someone visits your app without Javascript (i.e. search engine crawlers).

Comment: @mb21 the view directory & the partial directory

Comment: @Will M still don't follow, if my app has login, the crawler will get to the login page with or without javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Express is [server-side](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side), Angular [client-side](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client-side). Since search engine crawlers don't execute your JavaScript, everything (including every route) that you want them to see need to be done by express (i.e. express routes in the `views` directory), the rest you can do with Angular (Angular templates in `partials`).

Also, see the related questions on the right.

Comment: but then it means that express needs to handle the angular routes as well. e.g. // Routes
app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/partials/:name', routes.partials); <-- these are client side routing.

Comment: from express' point of view, all angular files are just static files. So simply serve them using `express.static(__dirname + '/angular')`

Comment: sorry guys, I still don't understand, why server should care who is the client and how it works. from my pov, the client code should be under the public directory.for crawlers the server should create a seo file which has nothing to do with the partial views & etc (sitemap.xml).

Comment: maybe reading http://code-inside.de/blog-in/2012/07/06/client-side-vs-server-side-html-rendering/ and https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/learn-more helps.